# Gridview to working when asp.net page linked to master page

Tags: asp.net, gridview

For some reason my gridview works in an ASP.net page without a master but when I link to a master page the gridview doesnt show. Heres the code i'm using.

```
<%@ Page Title="Patients" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="showAllPatients.aspx.cs" Inherits="showAllPatients" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="100%"  ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    </asp:GridView>


</asp:Content>
```

Why could this be?

Here is the master page in all its glory

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    Doctors Booking Systems
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/showAllPatients.aspx" Text="Show All Patients"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/AddPatient.aspx" Text="Add A Patient"/>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls share Masterpage code also

Comment: AutoEventWireup="true"  ...  make the change in aspx page .It will works

Comment: thank you very much. I cant mark you down as an answer though unless you answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a small change in your aspx code Page Directive
AutoEventWireup="true"  (make it as a true)
If It works , mark as answer.